# SAML authentication failing

Tags: java, active-directory, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

I am gettinng below error while authenticating user using SAML token

> Failed to authenticate the user that belongs to the security domain
>   RJD and uses SAML authentication mode for the following reason:
>   [[SAML_0004] SAML token validation failed because of the following
>   reason: [[SAML_0007] The current time [Sunday September-24-2017
>   16:59:00.698 IST] exceeds the validity range for the SAML token, which
>   is from [Sunday September-24-2017 16:59:00.698 IST to Sunday
>   September-24-2017 16:59:00.698 IST].].].

Below is the piece of code

```
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext;
Subject subject = new Subject();
LoginContext lc = new LoginContext(appName, subject, callbackHandler, loginConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

It might look like you have to increese the time a token is valid. There should be some setting for this in the sofware you are using. Try that.

Comment: IDP and web application time should be same

Comment: Yes but in this case it does not seem to be the problem. As you see, the current time for the sp and the assertion validity is the same

Comment: I syn both server and client time and it started working

Comment: Ok, interesting.